# How to Do a http eavesdropper or proxy app on android

Tags: android, http, networking, proxy

The use case is that:

- all the applications on the android phone would connect to internet through a wifi.
- And I want to have an application that eavesdrops on the http traffic from all apps so that I can find what sites they visit.
- This application would be distributed as an apk and users would install this app on their phone.

How do I achieve this ?

I will tell what I tried:

- Used a Custom Vpn Service application where an activity triggers a service derived from VpnService.
- The Custom VpnService calls builder and sets Mtu, addRoute, addAddress, and then addDnsServer.
- Then the service reads from the file descriptor associated with the interface generated from builder's establish() call.

Now if the addRoute is called with ("0.0.0.0", 0), Iam able to intercept the traffic and see packet contents. But Iam not able to route the packets without creating udp tunnel to an external server which I dont want to do.

If the addRoute is called with the Wifi router IP, then routing automatically happens for all packets generated. But I am not able to intercept the packets on the file descriptor associated with the virtual interface. It simply doesnt receive any data on read() call.

What I want to do is:

- intercept the traffic to inspect the http headers
- at the same time, do routing as usual like a normal wifi connection does.
- Have everything self contained in the phone. There should be no external server.
- this appliction should not require any rooting or such. It should install the way a normal app does.

Comment: I am watching this question out of Curiosity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest *1) setting a proxy* and *2) running an app which acts as one*. The combination of these two won't require root privileges.

**SETTING THE PROXY**

This first point is probably the most tricky one. The only way of setting a software-level proxy (without requiring root) is by navigating to the Wi-Fi connection settings and manually set the proxy. However, there is an open-source application that can eventually bypass this particular step: [ProxySettings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lechucksoftware.proxy.proxysettings).

**INTERCEPTING THE TRAFFIC**

In my opinion, your best bet is using SandroProxy, an open-source proxy application for Android. It is extremely well written, currently maintained and supported, and will allow you to intercept the HTTP traffic and even modify it. The code can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/sandrop/), while the example application can be found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy).

---

This solution should fulfil all of your requirements:

1. Intercept the traffic (even edit it): thanks to the proxy setting, all the network traffic goes through the proxy address, which corresponds to your application
2. Edit is optional: everything will keep working as no proxy is set
3. Everything is local: no need for external servers, your proxy is the installed application
4. No root is required

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Iam convinced about point 2 you mentioned after looking at the sandroproxy app code and details to some extent. But regarding point no.1, Iam not able to understand what can be done to automate the process, even after looking at the proxy settings app code. It mentions that any individual app needs to be coded such that it uses the proxy settings entered in the "proxy settings" app. But in my case, its absolutely out of question to ask the other apps to fall in line with the proxy settings app. So how do I solve this problem ? Pls help.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you have no way of forcing other apps to honor the proxy settings. However, a proxy that is set using either the Wi-Fi settings or the ProxySettings app will be honored by most apps (with a few exceptions). This is purely based on my experience (I had to do this very task for my M.Sc thesis), for which I had to analyze several apps using this technique.

Comment: To that extent, if you programmatically set a proxy the way Proxy Settings does, you will have most apps to honor this setting and you will be able to intercept and analyze all the traffic by using SandroProxy. Got it?

Comment: Got it.. But could you pls point to specific code snippets inside Proxy settings app code which actually does the work. I feel like Iam in a sea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I haven't fiddled with the code, but something like this looks promising: https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy/blob/master/android-proxy-library/src/main/java/be/shouldit/proxy/lib/WiFiApConfig.java#L148.

Comment: I suggest you to clone the repository, build the app and then trace the calls to the point where the proxy is set for the currently connected Wi-Fi AP. Should take that long and it's a pretty easy thing to do ;)